# Q: How often is an LDAP user store refreshed in WSO2 Identity Server?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using WSO2 Identity Server 5.0.0. I have setup a primary read-only LDAP connection in user-mgt.xml. I created a new group on the LDAP server to assign permissions in the Roles section. The new group is not listed. How long does it take to refresh the LDAP groups and is there a way to force a refresh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally LDAP groups are read on-demand when it is listed down in the UI.  If you have more then 1000 groups in the LDAP,  then all the group would not be listed down in the UI.

If you mentioned about the roles under users.. It means that assigned roles for the users... Yes.. there is cache in WSO2IS  called `userRoleCache` which will cache the roles for given user.  This cache would be refreshed after 15min. Currently you can not configure this timeout value.  If you want, you can completely disable the cache using following user store manager property (in `user-mgt.xml` file)

`<Property name="UserRolesCacheEnabled">true</Property>`